# Assembley resolver não é chamado numa console application

Tags: c#

Olá. Tenho uma console application que é executada numa pasta diferente da pasta onde estão as assemblies core do ERP PRIMAVERA que necessito de usar. O problema é que quando executa a minha aplicação, ela diz que não encontra as dependências.

Tenho um assembly resolver para indicar a pasta onde estão as minhas dependncias mas ele nunca chega a ser chamado. O que está mal?

```
     class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
                currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

                EnumTipoPlataforma Plat = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial;
                string Empresa = "Demo";
                string User = "Teste";
                string Password = "";

                ErpBS Erp = new ErpBS();
                StdBETransaccao objStdTransac = new StdBETransaccao();
                Erp.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(Plat, Empresa, User, Password, objStdTransac, "DEFAULT");
            }


            static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
            {
                string assemblyFullName;
                System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;
                const string PRIMAVERA_API_FILES_FOLDER = @"PRIMAVERA\SG100\Apl"; //pasta da API do Primavera
                assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
                assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), PRIMAVERA_API_FILES_FOLDER), assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
                    return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
                else
                    return null;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A utilização do assembly resolver pressupõe que antes de qualquer chamada/utilização das referências externas, este seja instanciado sempre em **primeiro** **lugar**, isto é, tem de ser a primeira coisa que a aplicação faz.

No caso da console application é colocar isso no construtor da classe.

```
class Program
    {
        // Defenir aqui o resolver.
        static Program()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnumTipoPlataforma Plat = EnumTipoPlataforma.tpEmpresarial;
            string Empresa = "Demo";
            string User = "sergio.sereno";
            string Password = "qualquer";

            ErpBS Erp = new ErpBS();
            StdBETransaccao objStdTransac = new StdBETransaccao();
            Erp.AbreEmpresaTrabalho(Plat, Empresa, User, Password, objStdTransac, "DEFAULT");
        }

        static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string assemblyFullName;
            System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;
            const string PRIMAVERA_API_FILES_FOLDER = @"PRIMAVERA\SG100\Apl"; //pasta da API do Primavera
            assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
            assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), PRIMAVERA_API_FILES_FOLDER), assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```